# Getting the Promise dates across weeks for an order

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to pull the current promise date and the promise date 7 days ago, promise date 14 days ago, promise date 28 days ago with respect to the field date_value...The field prmdate is the promisedate

The promise date corresponding to the latest date_value is the current promise date...

The recdate is the latest date_value, rec1date is date_value-7, rec2date is date_value-14, rec3date is date_value-28

The input table for one sample order is as below

| order | Model | ord date | date_value | prmDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 6/7/2022 | 6/9/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 6/5/2022 | 6/9/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 6/4/2022 | 6/8/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 6/3/2022 | 6/8/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 6/2/2022 | 6/8/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/31/2022 | 6/7/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/27/2022 | 6/7/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/25/2022 | 6/7/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/24/2022 | 6/7/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/20/2022 | 6/5/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/18/2022 | 6/5/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/15/2022 | 6/5/2022 |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/10/2022 | 6/5/2022 |

The output table is

| order | Model | ord date | cur prm date | recdate | recdate1 | recdate2 | recdate3 | prm date -7D | prm date -14 D | prm date -28 D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 6/9/2022 | 6/7/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 5/24/2022 | 5/10/2022 | 6/7/2022 | 6/7/2022 | 6/5/2022 |

```
Input

create table ##input
(order varchar(20),
model varchar(40),
orddate date,
date_value date,
prmdate date)

insert into ##input values
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','6/7/2022','6/9/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','6/5/2022','6/9/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','6/4/2022','6/8/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','6/3/2022','6/8/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','6/2/2022','6/8/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/31/2022','6/7/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/27/2022','6/7/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/25/2022','6/7/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/24/2022','6/7/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/20/2022','6/5/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/18/2022','6/5/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/15/2022','6/5/2022'),
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','5/10/2022','6/5/2022')


output


create table ##output
(order varchar(20),
model varchar(40),
orddate date,
prmdate date,
recdate date,
rec1date date,
rec2date date,
rec3date date,
prmdate-7d date,
prmdate-14d date,
prmdate-28d date)

insert into ##output values
('B67189','mcx2134','9/24/2021','6/9/2022','6/7/2022',05/31/2022','05/24/2022','05/10/2022','6/7/2022','6/7/2022','6/5/2022')
```

**Coding Attempt**

```
with c1 as(
select order, model,orddate,

case when date_value=max(date_value) then prmdate 
else ''
end as cur prmdate,
max(date_value) as recdate,
  DATE_SUB(date_value, INTERVAL 7 DAY) as recdate1,
 DATE_SUB(date_value, INTERVAL 14 DAY) as recdate2,
 DATE_SUB(date_value, INTERVAL 28DAY) as recdate3
group by order,model,orddate
)

select a.*,
case when date_value=recdate1 then prmdate
else '' end as prmdate-7d
case when date_value=recdate2 then prmdate
else '' end as prmdate-14d
case when date_value=recdate3 then prmdate
else '' end as prmdate-28d
group by order,model,orddate
```

**Updated Coding Attempt**

```
WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY "ORDER","ORD_DATE" ORDER BY "DATE_VALUE" DESC)AS RNum
 FROM input
 ),CTE2 AS
 (
 SELECT "ORDER","ORDDATE","PRMDATE","DATE_VALUE" AS recdate,
   DATE_SUB("DATE_VALUE", INTERVAL 7 DAY) as recdate1,
 DATE_SUB("DATE_VALUE", INTERVAL 14 DAY) as recdate2,
 DATE_SUB("DATE_VALUE", INTERVAL 28 DAY) as recdate3
 FROM CTE 
 WHERE RNum=1
 )
 SELECT C.ORDER,C.ORDDATE,C.PRMDATE,C.recdate,C.recdate1,C.recdate2,C.recdate3
       ,C1.PRM_DATE AS [prmdate-7],C2.PRM_DATE AS [prmdate-14],C3.PRM_DATE AS [prmdate-28]
 FROM CTE2 C 
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT "PRM_DATE" FROM input WHERE C.SLS_ORD="SLS_ORD"  AND C.ORD_DATE="ORD_DATE" AND C.recdate1="DATE_VALUE")C1
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT "PRM_DATE" FROM input WHERE C.SLS_ORD="SLS_ORD"  AND C.ORD_DATE="ORD_DATE" AND C.recdate2="DATE_VALUE")C2
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT "PRM_DATE" FROM input WHERE C.SLS_ORD="SLS_ORD"  AND C.ORD_DATE="ORD_DATE" AND C.recdate3="DATE_VALUE")C3
```

Comment: can you share your latest available coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: @lemon: I have updated my attempt

Comment: given the current `prmDate = 6/9/2022`, why the corresponding value of `prm_date-7days = 6/7/2022` and not something like `prm_date-7days = 6/2/2022`? @user3369545

Comment: @lemon: I am taking the prm_date corresponding to the date_value..The prmdate corresponding to the latest date_value for a order is the curprmdate, the prmdate corresponding to date_value-7 for an order is the prmdate-7...The prmdate corresponding to date_value-14 for an order is the prmdate-14

Comment: To your question the currentprmdate =6/9/2022 because the latest value for the date_value for the order B61789 is 6/7/2022 and the corresponding prmdate is 6/9/2022 , the date_value-7 is 5/31/2022 and the corresponding prmdate is 6/7/2022 and it is called prmdate-7d